# Tooltip with box shadow - microtip

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Is it possible to bring the arrowhead in the front of tooltip from the microtip library?, I'm trying to add shadow to the entire tooltip but the head pointing down is on the back, so it gets blocked. Tried adding a background image to after but it's not working correctly.

Here's the code:

```
&[aria-label][role="tooltip"] {
  --microtip-font-size: 15px;
  &::after {
    box-shadow: 5px 9px 45px 4px darkgrey;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
    background-color: white;
    color: #000080;
  }
}


<button type="button" name="button" class='undo' aria-label="Undo" data-microtip-position="top" role="tooltip"></button>
```

Comment: im using the library 'microtip' and just modifying the values so i can customize it on css

Comment: Did you try to give z-index?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal yes, it's not working either. Im not really familiar with the microtip lib

Comment: @Bhuwan the box does get the shadow but the arrowhead just sticks in the back and its not visible because of the shadow

Comment: That is not CSS in the question; please provide the compiled CSS unless the issue you're having is specifically how to do something with a CSS preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tooltip content is in `:after` and arrow is in `:before` and `:after` comes up than `:before` if no `z-index` is defined...

Try to define the `z-index` of arrow i.e. `[aria-label][role~="tooltip"]:before`...

```
[aria-label][role~="tooltip"]:before {
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of a tooltip that might help out without overcomplicating things.

```css
/* Tooltip container */

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}


/* Tooltip text */

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">

  <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>

  <p>Just note that the position of the tooltip text isn't very good.</p>

</body>

</html>
```